# Produce Bar Chart of Filtered Columns with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, data-visualization, summarize

[image: Expected Result]

Could you please tell me how I can produce the graph as shown? 
I want to select only the top 2 neighbourhoods for each city (top 2 neighbourhoods based on the median housing prices) and show their median prices. Of course, it is much nicer if the bars are of different colors.. 
(Please note that I manually produce the median price and plot it in Excel, so they are not representative of the real values)

```
    glimpse(CityNeighbourhoodPrice)
Observations: 37,245
Variables: 3
$ City          <fct> Amsterdam, Amsterdam, Amsterdam...
$ Neighbourhood <fct> A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K...
$ Price         <int> 970, 1320, 2060, 2480, 1070, 12...
```

Here is my code so far (that doesn't work):

```
CityNeighbourhoodPrice %>% 
  group_by(Neighbourhood) %>%
  count(n) %>%
  top_n(2, MedPrice) %>%
  summarise(MedPrice = median(Price, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(Neighbourhood,-MedPrice), y = MedPrice)) +
  geom_col(fill = "tomato3", width = 0.5)+
  labs(title="Ordered Bar Chart", 
       subtitle="Average Price by each Property Type", 
       caption="Image: 5") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=65, vjust=0.6))
```

Comment: Please include the dataset or a subset of the dataset in your question. It looks as if you only need data from City, Neighbourhood and Price. And maybe explain what the letters A, B, C... mean and where they come from.

Comment: What do the letters A, B, C... mean, it looks as if they reflect some measure of "topness" - how is this defined or what variable caputures this attribute? (sorry only allowed 5 min to edit a comment!)

Comment: Hi, sorry. The A,B,C refers to neighbourhood! The dataset is provided in the question, I believe? I would like to take only the top 2 neighbourhoods. The top 2 neighbourhoods are determined based on the MEDIAN PRICE. I will clarify the question @Peter

Comment: Thanks. You have provided a view of the dataset but it is not easy to copy and paste  so that it can be used to answer the question. Can you provide an extract, maybe using `dput()` in the form of a dataframe including only the variables which are applicable to your question. See [mre] for examples of what and how to do this if you are not sure. It will make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure how to use dput(), I have edited my question to include only the variables needed..

Comment: Also, @Tony Flager what have you tried yourself already? An important rule of SO is that questions should not be submitted in the form of assignments for others. They need to show your own attempt and research before asking a specific question about a single part of the process that you can't move forward from. Your current question is not one but multiple in one.

Comment: @ Yach I am trying to help answer the question I am not posing the question! Tony Flager is asking the question.

Comment: oh apologies haha

Comment: Thanks, however there is an issue with `dput()` as  SO is not able to handle >30,000 date points! So a filtered subset of the data is required. Take your time and read up about how to do this - it may help you answering your own question.

Comment: @Yach, no problems

Comment: I am not exactly sure how else I should do a subset of my data, especially because I have used the dplyr function `select` to only include 3 columns.. The code that I can think of right now is in the edit.

Comment: @TonyFlager see the update answer I posted. The title is added.

Comment: @TonyFlager sorry just realised I had countries instead of cities. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using some random example data, try this:

```r
# Example data
set.seed(42)

CityNeighbourhoodPrice <- data.frame(
  City = rep(c("Amsterdam", "Berlin", "Edinburgh"), each = 30),
  Neighbourhood = rep(sample(LETTERS[1:5], 30, replace = TRUE), 3),
  Price = 3000 * runif(3 * 30)
)

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

# Plot
CityNeighbourhoodPrice %>% 
  group_by(City, Neighbourhood) %>%
  summarise(MedPrice = median(Price, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  top_n(2, MedPrice) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  arrange(City, MedPrice) %>% 
  mutate(City_Neighbourhood = paste0(Neighbourhood, "\n", City),
         City_Neighbourhood = forcats::fct_inorder(City_Neighbourhood)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = City_Neighbourhood, y = MedPrice)) +
  geom_col(fill = "tomato3", width = 0.5)+
  labs(title="Ordered Bar Chart", 
       subtitle="Average Price by each Property Type", 
       caption="Image: 5") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=65, vjust=0.6))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be:

let's say your data looks like:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot)

data <- data.frame(Price=c(970, 245, 564, 895, 431, 100), City=c("Amsterdam", "Athens", "Amsterdam", "London", "Berlin", "Netherlands"), Neighborhood=c("A", "B", "D", "C", "E", "F"))
```

Then you do:

```
example_plot <- data %>%
  select(Price, City, Neighborhood) %>%
  group_by(City) %>%
  top_n(., 2, wt=Price) %>%
  spread(Neighborhood, Price) %>%
  data.frame %>%
  mutate(., Average=rowMeans(.[,-1], na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ggplot(., aes(City, Average, fill=City)) +
  ggtitle(str_wrap(c("Median Price for the Top-2 Neighborhoods in Different Cities:"), 20)) +
  theme_fivethirtyeight() +
  theme(legend.position = "none", plot.title = element_text(size= 22), axis.text = element_text(size=14))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(x = City, y = Average, label = Average ), colour = "white", size = 11, vjust=1.2)
```

And it gives you:

[image]

Comment: I am sorry, the output provided by Stefan is the most similar to my expectation, as I expect each city to be split into two neighbourhoods. Thanks a lot for your effort!